# Get schema table name using database migration name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration, schema

Actually, I need the table name `users` from Table Migration File using the migration table path. Is it possible? if yes, then how?

**Path of Migration Table:**

```
\database\migrations\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

**Code in User Table Migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

**Other Migrations Name and Location in array**

```
$migration = [
      0 => "2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php",
      1 => "2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php",
      2 => "2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table.php",
      3 => "2016_06_01_000002_create_oauth_access_tokens_table.php",
      4 => "2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table.php",
      5 => "2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table.php",
      6 => "2016_06_01_000005_create_oauth_personal_access_clients_table.php",
      7 => "2017_10_04_100236_create_staff_designations_table.php",
      8 => "2017_10_05_003733_create_grading_types_table.php",
      9 => "2017_10_05_003849_create_grading_scales_table.php",
      10 => "2017_10_05_072329_create_staff_table.php",
      11 => "2017_10_06_085150_create_faculties_table.php",
      12 => "2017_10_06_085202_create_semesters_table.php"
        ]
```

Comment: you need to pull some arbitrary text from a migration file? I am not sure what "the migration table path" means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your main purpose.
but if you need all project's table name you can use it:

```
$tables = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
```